# How do I map two [String] into one [Record] in swift?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

**Problem**

I have two equal-length arrays of `[String]` that I would like to map into a `[Record]`.

`Record` has a constructor which takes an id for the record number (from 1 to n), and `str1` and `str2` for entries from `arr1` and `arr2`.

*How do I do this in swift using the functional paradigm?*

I know I can do this using a simple `for...in` loop, but I was wondering if there is a functional way of accomplishing the same.

**Swift Snippet**

```
struct Record
{
  var id : UInt         /* record number */
  var str1 : String
  var str2 : String
}

class Records
{
  var records : [Records]

  init()
  {
    var arr1 : [String]
    var arr2 : [String]
    /* assume arr1 and arr2 initialised to equal length arrays */
    records = ???   /* using functional paradigm, build using arr1, arr2 */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct Record
{
    var id : UInt         /* record number */
    var str1 : String
    var str2 : String
    init(id: UInt, str1: String, str2: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.str1 = str1
        self.str2 = str2
    }
}

class Records
{
    var records : [Record]

    init(arr1: [String], arr2: [String])
    {
        let count = min(arr1.count, arr2.count)
        records = (0..<count).map { Record(id: UInt($0 + 1), str1: arr1[$0], str2: arr2[$0]) }
    }
}

let arr1 : [String] = ["one", "two", "three"]
let arr2 : [String] = ["uno", "dos", "tres"]

let recs = Records(arr1: arr1, arr2: arr2)
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about `$0` in `map(sequence, transform)`.

Comment: Or you can `zip` two arrays and map over resulting array of `(String, String)` tuples.